# Angular passing parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to learn AngularJs and I have this code shown in the image below from a course am watching. the author is doing `$http.get("url").then(function()...` . What I don't understand is that `onUserComplete` function accepts `response` parameter, but in the `then` function, he's not passing this `response` parameter, and the example works. From what I understand in JavaScript is that we should do like: `then(onUserComplete(response)) ;`  Can anyone exaplain it to me?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.then()` function takes a callback function as it's parameter. The callback function is stored in the variable `onUserComplete`. So when the author writes `.then(onUserComplete)`, `onUserComplete` is not being invoked, it's just being passed as a reference.

Comment: oooh, ok, I thought it's an invocation that's why I was expecting it to pass parameter, so it will pass `response` at invocation time  and I won't have to pass it?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you go over the documentation again : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

but to make a long story short:

.then basically wait for the promise to return, that means the response from the server arrived.

the response include parameter data with the data from the server (let's say json)

then is excpect function as parameter so the function name is subsitute for the function, in your case it's onUserComplete.

Have a look on similar example:

```
// Simple GET request example :
$http.get('/someUrl').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

`then` function will call your callback with response (data, actually) object.

Answer (score 0):

The `.then` expects a function as a parameter, which is exactly what `onUserComplete` is.

In a straightforward syntax, you would have seen:

```
.then(function (response) { 
    $scope.user = response.data;
});
```

And in a more common way, using anonymous syntax:

```
.then(response => 
    $scope.user = response.data;
);
```

So that's all there is to it. The `onUserComplete` is just a substitute.